# Can't append child to every DOM element in my array?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hey friends I have an array of elements. I want to add a child span element to each one. I used a for loop

```
for(let i = 0; i < slots.length; i++) {
    //add class to each div
    slots[i].classList.add('c' + i);
    //add the slot to each div
    slots[i].appendChild(slot);
    //add the function with the game logic to each slot
    slots[i].addEventListener('click', runGame); 
}
```

and watched each element append the child. But when I looked at the elements in my devtools the only element that had a span inside of it was the last one? Not all of them? Any ideas?

```js
//grab all slot positions on the board
const slots = document.querySelectorAll('.board div');
let player = 'p1';
let board = [
  0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,
  7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13,
  14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20,
  21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27,
  28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34,
  35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41,
]

let slot = document.createElement('span');


//assign a class to each slot to represent its position
for (let i = 0; i < slots.length; i++) {
  //add class to each div
  slots[i].classList.add('c' + i);
  //add the slot to each div
  slots[i].appendChild(slot);
  //add the function with the game logic to each slot
  slots[i].addEventListener('click', runGame);
}

function runGame() {
  //figure out which column the selected slot sits in
  const slotColumn = (Number(this.className.slice(1, 3)) % 7);
  //create an array to store all the slots that share the above column
  const columnArray = [];

  //grab all the slots that sit in that column
  for (let i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
    if (board[i] % 7 === slotColumn) columnArray.push(board[i]);
  }

  //drop chip in the chosen column
  dropChip(columnArray);

  function dropChip(column) {
    //select bottom most slot that's available in the column
    for (let i = column.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
      if (column[i] !== 'p1' || column[i] !== 'p2') {
        board[column[i]] = player;
        slots[column[i]].classList.add(player);
        switchPlayer(player);
        break;
      }
    }

    function switchPlayer(currentPlayer) {
      if (currentPlayer === 'p1') player = 'p2';
      else if (currentPlayer === 'p2') player = 'p1';
    }
    console.log(board);
  }
}
```

```css
/** {
 outline: 1px solid red;
}*/

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #e5e6e8;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.board-wrapper {
  padding-top: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: auto auto 0 auto;
  /*ask why this is needed*/
  position: relative;
}

.board {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 706px;
  background-color: #00c;
  padding: 3px;
}

.board div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  border: 3px solid #00c;
  position: relative;
}

.board div:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #00c;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 13px #0606aa;
}

.board .chip {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: transparent;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100px;
}

.board .chip:after {
  content: "";
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  left: 3px;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}

.board .chip:before {
  content: "";
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  left: 18px;
  top: 15px;
  z-index: 1;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 20px #cc0000;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}

.board div:nth-of-type(7n+1):hover~.chip:after {
  transform: translateX(10px);
  opacity: 1;
}

.board div:nth-of-type(7n+1):hover~.chip:before {
  transform: translateX(10px);
  opacity: 1;
}

.board div:nth-of-type(7n+2):hover~.chip:after {
  transform: translateX(110px);
  opacity: 1;
}

.board div:nth-of-type(7n+2):hover~.chip:before {
  transform: translateX(110px);
  opacity: 1;
}

.board div:nth-of-type(7n+3):hover~.chip:after {
  transform: translateX(210px);
  opacity: 1;
}

.board div:nth-of-type(7n+3):hover~.chip:before {
  transform: translateX(210px);
  opacity: 1;
}

.board div:nth-of-type(7n+4):hover~.chip:after {
  transform: translateX(310px);
  opacity: 1;
}

.board div:nth-of-type(7n+4):hover~.chip:before {
  transform: translateX(310px);
  opacity: 1;
}

.board div:nth-of-type(7n+5):hover~.chip:after {
  transform: translateX(410px);
  opacity: 1;
}

.board div:nth-of-type(7n+5):hover~.chip:before {
  transform: translateX(410px);
  opacity: 1;
}

.board div:nth-of-type(7n+6):hover~.chip:after {
  transform: translateX(510px);
  opacity: 1;
}

.board div:nth-of-type(7n+6):hover~.chip:before {
  transform: translateX(510px);
  opacity: 1;
}

.board div:nth-of-type(7n+7):hover~.chip:after {
  transform: translateX(610px);
  opacity: 1;
}

.board div:nth-of-type(7n+7):hover~.chip:before {
  transform: translateX(610px);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="board-wrapper">
  <div class="board">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <span class="chip"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to clone the `slot` element, otherwise it just moves from one parent to the next.

So I added `cloneNode()` to create a new clone for each location.

```js
//grab all slot positions on the board
const slots = document.querySelectorAll('.board div');
let player = 'p1';
let board = [
  0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,
  7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13,
  14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20,
  21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27,
  28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34,
  35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41,
]

let slot = document.createElement('span');


//assign a class to each slot to represent its position
for (let i = 0; i < slots.length; i++) {
  //add class to each div
  slots[i].classList.add('c' + i);
  //add the slot to each div
  slots[i].appendChild(slot.cloneNode()); //<--------------------------- cloneNode()
  //add the function with the game logic to each slot
  slots[i].addEventListener('click', runGame);
}

function runGame() {
  //figure out which column the selected slot sits in
  const slotColumn = (Number(this.className.slice(1, 3)) % 7);
  //create an array to store all the slots that share the above column
  const columnArray = [];

  //grab all the slots that sit in that column
  for (let i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
    if (board[i] % 7 === slotColumn) columnArray.push(board[i]);
  }

  //drop chip in the chosen column
  dropChip(columnArray);

  function dropChip(column) {
    //select bottom most slot that's available in the column
    for (let i = column.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
      if (column[i] !== 'p1' || column[i] !== 'p2') {
        board[column[i]] = player;
        slots[column[i]].classList.add(player);
        switchPlayer(player);
        break;
      }
    }

    function switchPlayer(currentPlayer) {
      if (currentPlayer === 'p1') player = 'p2';
      else if (currentPlayer === 'p2') player = 'p1';
    }
    console.log(board);
  }
}
```

```css
/** {
 outline: 1px solid red;
}*/

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #e5e6e8;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.board-wrapper {
  padding-top: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: auto auto 0 auto;
  /*ask why this is needed*/
  position: relative;
}

.board {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 706px;
  background-color: #00c;
  padding: 3px;
}

.board div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  border: 3px solid #00c;
  position: relative;
}

.board div:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #00c;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 13px #0606aa;
}

.board .chip {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: transparent;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100px;
}

.board .chip:after {
  content: "";
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  left: 3px;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}

.board .chip:before {
  content: "";
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  left: 18px;
  top: 15px;
  z-index: 1;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 20px #cc0000;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}

.board div:nth-of-type(7n+1):hover~.chip:after {
  transform: translateX(10px);
  opacity: 1;
}

.board div:nth-of-type(7n+1):hover~.chip:before {
  transform: translateX(10px);
  opacity: 1;
}

.board div:nth-of-type(7n+2):hover~.chip:after {
  transform: translateX(110px);
  opacity: 1;
}

.board div:nth-of-type(7n+2):hover~.chip:before {
  transform: translateX(110px);
  opacity: 1;
}

.board div:nth-of-type(7n+3):hover~.chip:after {
  transform: translateX(210px);
  opacity: 1;
}

.board div:nth-of-type(7n+3):hover~.chip:before {
  transform: translateX(210px);
  opacity: 1;
}

.board div:nth-of-type(7n+4):hover~.chip:after {
  transform: translateX(310px);
  opacity: 1;
}

.board div:nth-of-type(7n+4):hover~.chip:before {
  transform: translateX(310px);
  opacity: 1;
}

.board div:nth-of-type(7n+5):hover~.chip:after {
  transform: translateX(410px);
  opacity: 1;
}

.board div:nth-of-type(7n+5):hover~.chip:before {
  transform: translateX(410px);
  opacity: 1;
}

.board div:nth-of-type(7n+6):hover~.chip:after {
  transform: translateX(510px);
  opacity: 1;
}

.board div:nth-of-type(7n+6):hover~.chip:before {
  transform: translateX(510px);
  opacity: 1;
}

.board div:nth-of-type(7n+7):hover~.chip:after {
  transform: translateX(610px);
  opacity: 1;
}

.board div:nth-of-type(7n+7):hover~.chip:before {
  transform: translateX(610px);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Connect Four</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="board-wrapper">
    <div class="board">
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <span class="chip"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I agree with @Mohd Asim Suhail and @Towkir. You can move the creation of `slot` into the loop. This is fine is all you are doing is creating the slot and not doing anything else to it. But if you create `slot` and then add classes and children then it is faster to use `cloneNode(true)`. (`true` will clone all children as well.)

Given how your example was written I would probably change it to look like this:

```js
//grab all slot positions on the board
const COLUMNS = 7;
const ROWS = 7;
const boardEl = document.querySelector('.board');
let player = 1;
let board = [];
boardEl.addEventListener('click', runGame);

let c = 0;

// Set up the board, assign a class to each slot to represent its position
for (let row = 0; row < ROWS; row++) {
  const newRow = [];
  for (let col = 0; col < COLUMNS; col++) {
    newRow.push(0);
    slot = document.createElement('div');
    slot.classList.add('c' + c++);  //add class to each div
    slot.setAttribute('col', col);
    slot.setAttribute('row', row);
    slot.innerHTML = '<span></span>'; //add the slot to each div
    boardEl.appendChild(slot);
  }

  board.push(newRow);
}

const chip = document.createElement('span');
chip.className = 'chip';
boardEl.appendChild(chip);


function switchPlayer() {
  player = player === 1 ? 2 : 1;
}

function dropChip(col) {
  const colData = board[col];
  
  //select bottom most slot that's available in the column
  for (let i = ROWS-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (colData[i] === 0) {
      colData[i] = player;
      const el = boardEl.querySelector(`[col="${col}"][row="${i}"]`)
      el.classList.add(`p${player}`);
      break;
    }
  }

  switchPlayer(player);
}


function runGame(evt) {
  let slot = evt.target;
  // If they clicked on the `<span>` the move to the `<div>`
  if (slot.nodeName === 'SPAN') {
    slot = slot.parentElement;
  }

  //figure out which column the selected slot sits in
  const col = Number(slot.getAttribute('col'));

  //drop chip in the chosen column
  dropChip(col);
}
```

```css
/** {
 outline: 1px solid red;
}*/

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #e5e6e8;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.board-wrapper {
  padding-top: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: auto auto 0 auto;
  /*ask why this is needed*/
  position: relative;
}

.board {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 706px;
  background-color: #00c;
  padding: 3px;
}

.board div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  border: 3px solid #00c;
  position: relative;
}

.board div:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #00c;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 13px #0606aa;
}

.board .chip {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: transparent;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100px;
}

.board .chip:after {
  content: "";
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  left: 3px;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}

.board .chip:before {
  content: "";
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  left: 18px;
  top: 15px;
  z-index: 1;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 20px #cc0000;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}

.board div:nth-of-type(7n+1):hover~.chip:after {
  transform: translateX(10px);
  opacity: 1;
}

.board div:nth-of-type(7n+1):hover~.chip:before {
  transform: translateX(10px);
  opacity: 1;
}

.board div:nth-of-type(7n+2):hover~.chip:after {
  transform: translateX(110px);
  opacity: 1;
}

.board div:nth-of-type(7n+2):hover~.chip:before {
  transform: translateX(110px);
  opacity: 1;
}

.board div:nth-of-type(7n+3):hover~.chip:after {
  transform: translateX(210px);
  opacity: 1;
}

.board div:nth-of-type(7n+3):hover~.chip:before {
  transform: translateX(210px);
  opacity: 1;
}

.board div:nth-of-type(7n+4):hover~.chip:after {
  transform: translateX(310px);
  opacity: 1;
}

.board div:nth-of-type(7n+4):hover~.chip:before {
  transform: translateX(310px);
  opacity: 1;
}

.board div:nth-of-type(7n+5):hover~.chip:after {
  transform: translateX(410px);
  opacity: 1;
}

.board div:nth-of-type(7n+5):hover~.chip:before {
  transform: translateX(410px);
  opacity: 1;
}

.board div:nth-of-type(7n+6):hover~.chip:after {
  transform: translateX(510px);
  opacity: 1;
}

.board div:nth-of-type(7n+6):hover~.chip:before {
  transform: translateX(510px);
  opacity: 1;
}

.board div:nth-of-type(7n+7):hover~.chip:after {
  transform: translateX(610px);
  opacity: 1;
}

.board div:nth-of-type(7n+7):hover~.chip:before {
  transform: translateX(610px);
  opacity: 1;
}

.board span {
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 80px;
  left: 10px;
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  width: 80px;
  z-index: 999;
}
.board .p1 span {
  background-color: red;
}

.board .p2 span {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Connect Four</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="board-wrapper">
    <div class="board">
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

This version of the code converts your board into a double-dimension array, only requires one event handler and works, most of the way.

Comment: how about defining the `let slot = document.createElement('span');` inside the loop ? a new element is created per cycle and appended too.

Comment: Yes, you can do that too. I am not sure which way would be faster. Unless there is a large amount of setup of `slot` then `cloneNode` is probably faster then recreating it all over and over.

Comment: why would that change anything? slot exits as a global so I shouldn't have to create a new one with each iteration?

Comment: @Alfred because `appendChild` does not copy an element, it moves an element so, each cycle moves the element to the next parent element, and finally you find it in the last parent once the loop ends. thats why you need to `clone` it or create a new one

Answer (score 0):

You can just move

`let slot = document.createElement('span');`

line inside the for loop to solve the problem.

Refer to this [link](https://blog.angularindepth.com/here-is-why-appendchild-moves-a-dom-node-instead-of-cloning-it-f8ef7a31735c) for further understanding the behavior of appendChild in DOM.